# What if someone ditched into my apps code files and memory and found my Mapbox's access token key?

Tags: android, ios, mapbox, access-token, nativescript-plugin

I use Mapbox native SDK plugin for my app to build my native app with Mapbox for Android and iOS. But what if someone hacked my app files and found my access token key to Mapbox service that I use in my app. What if they use it in their apps or abuse the access token?

Answer (score 2):

Access token abuse is definitely something to take seriously. Mapbox has an in-depth guide that lists recommendations for preventing malicious token use: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/how-to-use-mapbox-securely/#access-tokens

Of course, even the most secure apps can be reverse engineered. So the most important tips listed in that guide are that you keep an eye on your statistics page for any anomalies & regularly rotate your tokens.

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️